# for assign with R

Tags: r, for-loop

I tried to run this code (with no success):

```
for (i in chanel_code) {
  assign(paste("prospect_",i,sep="", collapse = NULL,recycle0 = FALSE),(aggregate(na_adss_score ~ month_year + na_appl_status, paste("new_account_",i, sep="",collapse = NULL, recycle0 = FALSE),mean) %>% 
                                                                          mutate(aggregate(na_pcn_no ~ month_year + na_appl_status,  paste("new_account_",i, sep="",collapse = NULL, recycle0 = FALSE), length))))
}
```

> *Error in eval(predvars, data, env) :
> argument 'envir' incorrect de type 'character'*

would you mind please helping me.

thanks in advance

Comment: with

chanel_code=c( "BA","CS","DM","DS","EN","IA","MG","PS","TM")

Comment: I don't know the rest of your code or context, but ... `assign(.)` is often not a sign of good data flow. Since you're doing the same thing to multiple things and are working with frame-like objects, I suggest you look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227, and become familiar with using `lapply`.

Comment: Side note, though: the second argument to `aggregate.formula` is `data=`, but you are sending it a `paste(.)` string. Even though the column names may be evaluated directly (because this is in a `mutate` context), you must then assign all other arguments to `aggregate` *by name*. (I cannot provide a recommendation because your code is confusing, hard-to-read, and the question is not [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).)

Comment: the code run perfectly for single argument                           :


prospect_BA=aggregate(na_adss_score ~ month_year + na_appl_status, new_account_BA,mean) %>%
  mutate(aggregate(na_pcn_no ~ month_year + na_appl_status, new_account_BA, length))
                                                              as I have to do this for 9 tables   :c( "BA","CS","DM","DS","EN","IA","MG","PS","TM")        I wish I could use the FOR

Comment: Hi @MoLo, were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `assign()` or all the arguments for `paste()`. Instead, subset your data with `i` and use `paste0()`.

Assuming your dataset is called `new_account_BA` and `new_account_BA$chanel_codes` contains chanel_codes:

```
chanel_code=c("BA","CS","DM","DS","EN","IA","MG","PS","TM")
results <- list()
for (i in chanel_code) {
  x <- new_account_BA[new_account_BA$chanel_code == paste0("prospect_",i),]
  results[[chanel_code]] <- cbind(
    aggregate(na_adss_score ~ month_year + na_appl_status, x = x, mean),
    aggregate(na_pcn_no ~ month_year + na_appl_status, x = x, length))
}
```